# in what cases should I use "out of" instead of "from"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, idiomatic-language

I heard a lot of natives speakers use "out of" instead of "from"

> she is out of Mexico

I want to know why do English speakers make that change

Comment: _She is out of Mexico_ is not something I would say. I think it is a regionalism, but I can't tell you what region it is peculiar to.

Comment: _"Out of"_ would mean she is away from Mexico at the moment. Whereas, _"from"_ would mean she belongs there, more like she was born and brought up in Mexico. But I am certainly unaware of using **out of** in place of **from**.

Comment: @ColinFine - I would say definitely US, and distinctly informal. They said it all the time on The Sopranos. He's a big shot outta Pittsburgh. I'm gonna whack his ass. I would think more a region or city than a country.